# ¿Cómo evitar que la Scrollbar vertical se salga del rango de su WebView?

Tags: android, android-layout, webview-android

Estoy tratando de desplegar simples archivos html con texto (sin javascript) algo extensos dentro de una webview, pero la scrollbar sobrepasa su altura y continúa bajando hasta el final de la página.

El `xml` de mi actividad:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout ...>

<include
    android:id="@+id/genericToolbar"
    layout="@layout/generic_toolbar" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/genericToolbar" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

El despliegue es bastante simple (En este ejemplo no se muestran las rutinas de conexión).

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_song_lyric);

    MarqueeToolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.genericToolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);


    webView.loadUrl("http://10.0.2.2/long_file.html");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    // ...
}
```

Puede parecer algo trivial pero es posible que esté omitiendo alguna configuración importante no mencionada en la documentación que considere la altura del contenedor.

[image: Problema con la altira maxima del contenedor del Scrollbar]

Comment: Hola revisa eliminando android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay", como curiosidad cual es el código que contiene tu pagina web.

Comment: Se trata de una conversión a html de archivos que originalmente eran texto plano, así que son muy simple , he aquí un ejemplo: https://pastebin.com/3wafKh82

Comment: hey @Chipkat Un poco raro lo que comentas, podrías agregar tu generic_toolbar.xml ?

Comment: He tratado eliminando el toolbar, pero ocurre lo mismo, de todas formas aquí está el layout completo mostrando el `generic_toolbar`. https://pastebin.com/WXvnw0tz

Comment: Me llama la atención también que con   android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp" no se mostraría nada, como se despliega en tu ejemplo ?

Comment: Cuando lo coloqué en el xml lo hice como `match_constraint`, pero al revisarlo en la vista de diseño de Android Studio convierte `match_constraint` a 0dp. Y aparentemente sigue teniendo este valor.

Comment: He realizado lo que tienes en tu pregunta y en mi caso funciona correctamente, puede ser que sea la versión de Chrome que funciona de una forma diferente, que sistema operativo Android usas? @ChipKat

Comment: @Jorgesys Android 7.1.1 API 25, he probado en Android 8.1 API 27  y en Android 7 API 24. Aunque ya he conseguido un dispositivo físico con Android 7.1.1 y al parecer si funciona correctamente en este último.